# Chutzpah runs "Out of stack space"

Tags: typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

I am using TypeScript 1.0 with Visual Studio 2012, Chutzpah 3.2.1.1 and Jasmine 2.

I have a very basic test which runs fine using the Visual Studio Chutzpah Test Adaptor

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
describe("x", function(){
    it("should", function(){
      expect("x").toEqual("x");  
    });
});
```

But I want to be able to run the tests on TeamCity, so I have created a MSBuild file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Chutzpah" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ChutzpahPath>..\packages\Chutzpah.3.2.1.1\tools\chutzpah.console.exe</ChutzpahPath>
    <TestSourcePath>Spec</TestSourcePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Chutzpah">
    <Exec Command="$(ChutzpahPath) $(TestSourcePath)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This run fines if all of my tests are written in JavaScript, but as soon as I add the above TypeScript tests I get the below error:

> EXEC : error : Out of stack space [config.xml]   While Running:x.ts

If it makes a difference, my tests are in one Visual Studio project and my TypeScript source files are a different project.

How can I get my TypeScript tests running?

Comment: That is odd that it works in the IDE but not the build file. If you file an issue on chutzpah.codeplex.com with a repro I can take a look. However, you should be using Chutzpah's compile setting (read about it [here](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20compile%20setting&referringTitle=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File)). This was released in Chutzpah 3.2 and it allows you to tell Chutzpah how to compile the code to JS (or if it should just assume the JS is compile externally and where to find it).

This is the recommended way for using TypeScript with Chutzpah now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have a public repo that I can share. I was originally using Chutzpah.json but was having problems, so I removed it and got the above stack errors. I have gone back to the .json file and will try to resolve my errors.